# How many parameters are present in a (general) discrete mixture of five normal distributions?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, nonparametric, finite-mixture-model

What is the minimal amount of parameters that can be retained in a particular context?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "retained" in this case?

Comment: For five _independent_ normal distributions, you would need to have the population means and standard deviations of the five distributions, and the percentage of the mixture for each normal distribution. I guess that makes 15, and they're all essential.

Comment: @Bruce The five proportions are related by the sum-to-unity equation, leaving only 14 parameters.

Comment: @whuber: Right about the 14 proportions, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the dimension is $n$, you need $n$ parameters for each mean vector and $(n^2+n)/2$ parameters for each covariance matrix in *general*. Additionally, if the number of mixture components is $m$, $m-1$ parameters are needed for mixture composition weights since they need to sum up to $1$. Special constraints over covariance matrices reduce this number of parameters needed.

Comment: are the $m-1$ parameters you mention the mixture weights themselves, or are they other supporting parameters? wouldn't there have to be $m$ mixture weights if there are $m$ mixture components because each weight is assigned to a different component?

Comment: @develarist yes, they're mixture weights. $m-1$ is enough because they'll add up to $1$, and the last one can be found from others.

Comment: but the expectation-maximization algorithm will in fact actively solve for all $m$ mixture weights, right

Comment: The algorithm should be decoupled from the model. E-M is not the only way of solving GMMs. In general, if you can derive a parameter from others, it's not counted towards free parameters.